# how much traffic can a packet filtering firewall _ implemented with iptables _can handle?

Tags: linux, firewalls, iptables

I am trying to build a packet filtering firewall, that supposed to serve in a network consisting of almost 100 host.

Can a firewall build with iptables do such a task?

What is the best linux distributions to build such a firewall on?

Comment: The most important question here is how much traffic are your hosts generating?

Comment: And of course the server's resources matter very much too.

Comment: iptables is not your constraint, nor is the linux distro you choose, it's your network and the firewall's hardware that will be the issue

Comment: My network is a college network, hosts in it are almost normal internet users

Comment: You need to know the architecture of the network. First thing you need is the total bandwidth you need to handle. That will define the machine(s) you need to create.

Comment: my 2 cents: keep the size of collision Domains down as small as possible

Answer (score 1):

Many companies use IPTables as the primary firewall for networks with thousands of hosts. Likewise **many commercial firewall products are based on IPTables** so yes this is not only acceptable but quite common.

You may need to be consider the bandwidth involved **and the number of packets per second** compared to the hardware you are using in extreme situations or have a very high-speed connection to the Internet but if your outgoing bandwidth is 20% less than the bandwidth of the ethernet card you are probably using it's unlikely to be an issue for most modern web or office traffic.

Using a modern distro that you feel comfortable administrating is probably the most important issue for distribution source. **IPTables is not skewed heavily toward any given distro**. A better question to ask here may be which distro is going to be easier for you to secure especially since you are using it as a firewall.

**Consider if you need to create separate secured segments** when architecting your firewall solution. It's easy to have multiple interfaces on an IPTables-based firewall and more isolation between infected desktops and servers can be really helpful.

Finally do consider using IPTables on all of your linux hosts. The concept of **Zero Trust Firewalling**, where each system is hardened and has it's own firewall rules tightly configured is much more secure than the traditional flat network design.

Don't rule out projects like [PfSense](https://pfsense.org/) https://pfsense.org/

I like to build mine from scratch but you may find a lot of features in a package like this helpful.

You may also want to look into projects like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) and possibly [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/). I could go into hundreds of other security projects but these might be a good starting point.